# DashDB local (docker) failed to start because database services didn't start

Tags: docker, dashdb

I encountered an error while deploying and starting dashDB local on RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.2. Here are the main steps of IBM's official tutorial, which I followed step-by-step.

1.Deployment first steps - downloading and running container:

```
docker run -d -it --privileged=true --net=host --name=dashDB -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/bludata0 -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/blumeta0 ibmdashdb/local:latest
```

2.Observe deployment logs:

```
docker logs -–follow dashDB
```

Deployment logs message - every other test passed, only this issue has occurred:

```
###############################
[2246008.449894] start_dashDB_local.sh[221]: Creating dashDB directories and dashDB instance
[2246010.566736] start_dashDB_local.sh[221]: dashDB instance creation failed.
[2246010.567268] start_dashDB_local.sh[221]: Retry the operation. If the same failure occurs, contact IBM Service.
```

3.Start dashDB services within Docker:

```
# docker exec -it dashDB start
```

Following message has turned up:

```
*************************************************
Starting services. This might take a while ...
*************************************************
Checking if dashDB needs to be upgraded/migrated ...
hostname: Name or service not known
Restart LDAP/LDAP-depended network services AND set OS to use LDAP Authentication ...
getsebool:  SELinux is disabled
Re-syncing dashDB global registry ...
Configuring dashDB database environment on node hs21qc01
dashDB failed to start on hs21qc01 because database services didn't start.
Retry the operation. If the same failure occurs, contact IBM Service.
```

Has anyone experienced an issue like me? I gave it another try on CentOS 7.2 as well, where problem was identical.

Many thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue resolving hostname inside the container. Can you run the following on the Docker host server:

```
hostname # Does this show the shortname (same as hostname -s) ?
hostname -l # Does this show FQDN or same output as hostname -s ?
hostname -i # Is this IP address associated with your public network interface ? ( you can run 'ip a s' to confirm )
```

Also the output of /etc/hosts from the Docker host server.

Finally status of SELinux ( run 'sestatus' on the Docker host ).
Please feel free to change the actual value

Comment: You are right, the problem was that Docker container had a different hostname from physical machine. After setting hostnames properly and redeploying the whole image it is working fine. Thank you once more!

Answer (score 0):

The dashDB Local product cannot be deployed on RHEL 7 with Docker 1.13.

After installing Docker, perform the following steps before attempting to deploy dashDB Local:

1. Issue the *systemctl stop docker* command.
2. Issue the *dockerd --storage-driver=devicemapper &* command.
3. Issue the *docker info* command. Ensure that the "Storage Driver"
   field in the output specifies "devicemapper".